# Connecting to a service using SQL-CLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, windows-services, sqlclr

Let me define the scenario first:

A service which listens to a specific port and it is required to communicate with this service through SQL Server. The stored procedure in SQL Server must send a command to specific port of external server and get the result (which is a simple true/false)

The question is whether the SQL-CLR can be of any benefit to me? Does SQL-CLR give me any means of connecting to a socket directly? Should I go for a web service instead of a windows service?

Please note that no other program or party will use the service except for the stored procedure. That would be great if you provide me with a link to an example of your answer.
[the version of SQL Server is not important and could be 2005 or 2008]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using CLR STP I can easily access the .net libraries and hence it makes developement very easy.